# Matching a date to the range it belongs in

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am using my vsts analytics view to create reports in Power BI.

I have a table with columns - `Iteration Start Date`, `Iteration End Date`, `Iteration Path`, `Work Item Id`, `Created Date`.

For some of the work items, I only have their `Created Date`, not `Iteration Start Date` and `Iteration End Date` (as they have not been added to any iteration yet).

However, I want to assign them an `Iteration Start Date`, `Iteration End Date` and `Iteration Path` based on where the `Created Date` fits in between all other existing `Iteration Start Date` and `Iteration End Date`.

For this, I need some way to compare the `Created Date` for work items for which `Iteration Start Date` and `Iteration End Date` are empty WITH all other rows `Iteration Start Date` and `Iteration End Date` and assign the `Iteration Start Date` and `Iteration End Date` where the `Created Date` fits.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

So, as shown in this image,

[image]

in new columns `New Iteration Start Date`, `New Iteration End Date` and `New Iteration Path` for work item id `363556` and `362314`, they should be set as `5/9/2018 12:00:00 AM`, `5/23/2018 12:00:00 AM` and `Intelligent Migration\Sprint 10 (5-22-2018)` respectively.

Similarly, for work item id `360507`, they should be set as `4/25/2018 12:00:00 AM`, `5/9/2018 12:00:00 AM` and `Intelligent Migration\Sprint 10 (5-22-2018)` respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is pick one of the ID values (using a max or min on all possible values) where your `Created ID` falls between the iteration start and end dates and then use that ID value to lookup the other column values in that row. For example, you can calculate the new start date as follows:

```
New Start = 
    VAR CreatedDate = Iterations[Created]
    VAR MatchID = MAXX(
                      FILTER(Iterations,
                          Iterations[Start] < CreatedDate &&
                          Iterations[End]  >= CreatedDate
                      ),
                      Iterations[ID])
    RETURN LOOKUPVALUE(Iterations[Start], Iterations[ID], MatchID)
```

(Note: I've assumed the table name is `Iterations` and abbreviated column names for legibility.)

To get the new end date and the new path, just replace the first argument of the lookup function with the appropriate columns.

Comment: Thank you so much Alexis! Solved my problem. Perfect solution. :-)